# Difference between keytool -genkey vs -genkeypair

Tags: keytool, csr

I am using `keytool` to create a [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request).

I wonder what is the difference between the options `-genkey` and `-genkeypair`. My understanding is that `-genkey` creates only *private key* and `-genkeypair` creates both *private* and *public* key.

If so, how do I get the *public key* of the *private key* which is created using `-genkey`?

Answer (score 35):

Per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html, this keytool flag was named -genkey in earlier releases. While the old name is still supported, -genkeypair is preferred going forward.

So essentially, both are the same

Answer (score 4):

Hi there in old version of java was named `-genkey` which is stil supported

This command was named `-genkey` in earlier releases. The old name is still supported in this release. The new name, `-genkeypair`, is preferred going forward.

[Keytool Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html)